# Matlab count the number of occurrences of a two columns

Tags: matlab, count

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I have a matrix A with two columns of integers that can be either greater or less than 1000.

```
  A=[4565,345;325,6843;4565,4565;321,9876;6843,321;6843,321;6843,6843;9876,9876;6843,9876]
```

And I have a second matrix B that indicates the possible correspondences between the numbers greater and less than 1000:

```
 B= [9876,321;6843,532;6843,325;4565,345]
```

I would like to obtain the two following two matrices.

The first result indicates the number of occurrences in matrix A:

```
 9876 321 1
 6843 321 2
 6843 325 1
 4565 345 1
```

The second result takes the rows of matrix A that only have numbers greater than 1000 and indicates the number of possible occurrences based on matrix B.

```
9876 321 2
6843 532 2
6843 325 2
4565 345 1
```

In order to solve the first part of the problem, I create an array C of this type:

```
C{1,1}=325   C{1,2}=6843
C{2,1}=321   C{2,2}=[9876,6843,6843]
C{3,1}=345   C{3,2}=4565
```

How could transform this array in order to have a matrix like the one of the first result?
I am using this code:

```
% find the unique elements in the input
uniqueBB=unique(finalA{1,2})';

%  find the occurences of this unique number in the data:
[~,uniq_id]=ismember(finalA{1,2},uniqueBB);

% count how many times each unique word is found:
uniq_BB_num = arrayfun(@(x) sum(uniq_id==x),1:numel(uniqueBB));

%transpose
uniqueBB = transpose(uniqueBB);
uniq_BB_num = transpose(uniq_BB_num);

counts=[uniqueBB,uniq_BB_num];
```

It it possible to do it in one time for all numbers less than 1000?

Finally, for the second part of the problem I would count the number of occurrences of numbers greater than 1000 of matrix A that do not have a corresponding number less than 1000 (i.e. 3465 and 6843) and I would multiply them with matrix B.

I hope I have been able to explain me.
If yes, thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for the first result:

```
A = [4565,345;325,6843;4565,4565;321,9876;6843,321;6843,321;6843,6843;9876,9876;6843,9876]
A_cols = {num2cell(A(:,1)'),num2cell(A(:,2)')};
A_rows = cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],A_cols{:},'un',0);
A_flippedlo_rows = cellfun(@(x) feval(@(varargin) varargin{3-varargin{1}}(), x{1}<x{2}, fliplr(x), x), A_rows, 'un', 0);

boolvec = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) bitand(x{1}>1000, x{2}<1000),A_flippedlo_rows,'un',0));
A_hilo_rows = A_flippedlo_rows(boolvec);
A_hilo_cols = cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],A_hilo_rows{:},'un',0);
A_hilo = [cell2mat(A_hilo_cols{1});cell2mat(A_hilo_cols{2})]'
[A_hilo_unique, iA_hilo, iA_hilo_unique] = unique(A_hilo, 'rows');
firstresult = [A_hilo_unique accumarray(iA_hilo_unique, ones(1,length(A_hilo)))]

A =
    4565         345
     325        6843
    4565        4565
     321        9876
    6843         321
    6843         321
    6843        6843
    9876        9876
    6843        9876

A_hilo =
    4565         345
    6843         325
    9876         321
    6843         321
    6843         321

firstresult =
    4565         345           1
    6843         321           2
    6843         325           1
    9876         321           1
```

Best I can do for the second result:

```
boolvec = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) bitand(x{1}>1000, x{2}>1000),A_flippedlo_rows,'un',0));
A_hihi_rows = A_flippedlo_rows(boolvec);
A_hihi_cols = cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],A_hihi_rows{:},'un',0);
A_hihi = [cell2mat(A_hihi_cols{1});cell2mat(A_hihi_cols{2})]'
A_hihi_joinkeys = cell2mat(A_hihi_cols{2});

B = [9876,321;6843,532;6843,325;4565,345]
Bkeys = B(:,1)';
Bvals = B(:,2)';
[Bkeys_unique,ia,ic] = unique(Bkeys);
if ~iscolumn(ic) %Matlab prior to 2013 did not output a column vector
 ic = ic';
end
Bvals_grouped = accumarray(ic,Bvals,{},@(x) {sort(x)})';
Bvals_grouped = cellfun(@(x) num2cell(x'), Bvals_grouped, 'un', 0);
[Lia, iBkeys_unique] = ismember(A_hihi_joinkeys,Bkeys_unique);

A_hihi_cols{2} = Bvals_grouped(iBkeys_unique);
A_hihi_rows = cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],A_hihi_cols{:},'un',0);

A_hihi_expanded_rows = cellfun(@(x) {repmat({x{1}},1,length(x{2})),x{2}}, A_hihi_rows, 'un', 0);
A_hihi_expanded_rows = cellfun(@(x) cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],x{:},'un',0), A_hihi_expanded_rows, 'un', 0);
A_hihi_expanded_rows = [A_hihi_expanded_rows{:}];
A_hihi_expanded_cols = cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],A_hihi_expanded_rows{:},'un',0);
A_hihi_expanded = [cell2mat(A_hihi_expanded_cols{1});cell2mat(A_hihi_expanded_cols{2})]'
[A_hihi_expanded_unique, iA_hihi_expanded, iA_hihi_expanded_unique] = unique(A_hihi_expanded, 'rows');
secondresult = [A_hihi_expanded_unique accumarray(iA_hihi_expanded_unique, ones(1,length(A_hihi_expanded_unique)))]


A_hihi =

    4565        4565
    6843        6843
    9876        9876
    9876        6843


B =

    9876         321
    6843         532
    6843         325
    4565         345


A_hihi_expanded =

    4565         345
    6843         325
    6843         532
    9876         321
    9876         325
    9876         532


secondresult =

    4565         345           1
    6843         325           1
    6843         532           1
    9876         321           1
    9876         325           1
    9876         532           1
```

---

To convert array C to the aggregate count matrix:

```
C{1,1}=325; C{1,2}=6843; 
C{2,1}=321; C{2,2}=[9876,6843,6843];
C{3,1}=345; C{3,2}=4565;
C
C_cols = {C(:,1)' C(:,2)'}; %convert to nested cells
C_cols{2} = cellfun(@(x) num2cell(x), C_cols{2}, 'un', 0);
C_rows = cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],C_cols{:},'un',0); %transpose to rows
C_rows = cellfun(@(x) {repmat({x{1}},1,length(x{2})),x{2}}, C_rows, 'un', 0); %repeat lo to length(hi)
C_rows = cellfun(@(x) cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],x{:},'un',0), C_rows, 'un', 0); %mix lo and 
C_rows = [C_rows{:}]; %expand
C_cols = cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],C_rows{:},'un',0); %transpose to cols
C_mat = [cell2mat(C_cols{2});cell2mat(C_cols{1})]';
[C_mat_unique, iC_mat, iC_mat_unique] = unique(C_mat, 'rows');
C_out = [C_mat_unique accumarray(iC_mat_unique, ones(1,length(C_rows)))]

C = 
[325]    [      6843]
[321]    [1x3 double]
[345]    [      4565]


C_out =
    4565         345           1
    6843         321           2
    6843         325           1
    9876         321           1
```

---

The following is the old reply to the original post

I wasn't able to understand some of your post:

- First, the matrixes displayed cannot contain blanks, they must either be 0 or NaN
- Second, I don't understand the last matrix -- if A is filtered to high integers then the output can't have low integer headings or all their counts would be zero

The following code should produce the other resulting matrix:

```
A = [4565 345;325 6843;4565 4565;321 9876;6843 321;6843 321;6843 6843;9876 9876;6843 nan;nan 9876];
a_cols = {num2cell(A(:,1)'),num2cell(A(:,2)')};
a_rows = feval(@(x) cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],x{:},'un',0),a_cols);
a_rows_hilo = cellfun(@(x) feval(@(varargin) varargin{3-varargin{1}}(), x{1}<x{2}, fliplr(x), x), a_rows, 'un', 0);
bm = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) bitand(x{1}>1000, x{2}<1000),a_rows_hilo,'un',0));
a_rows_valid = a_rows_hilo(bm);
a_cols_valid = feval(@(x) cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],x{:},'un',0),a_rows_valid);
[labels_hi,ia,subs(:,1)] = unique(cell2mat(a_cols_valid{1}));
[labels_lo,ia,subs(:,2)] = unique(cell2mat(a_cols_valid{2}));
agg_count = accumarray(subs,ones(1,length(a_rows_valid)));
agg_count = [[NaN labels_hi]' [labels_lo;agg_count]]

agg_count = 
 NaN         321         325         345
4565           0           0           1
6843           2           1           0
9876           1           0           0
```

EDIT: The original post has changed, i'll have to re-examine it all

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question and I tried to make it more clear. It is true missing numbers are replaced with NaN. I tried to run the code for a bigger matrix. The output is great. However it doesn't look to work.I do not find correspondences between higher and lower numbers. Why in the first column there is a NaN?

Comment: The first column contained a NaN because it was the best way to represent the intersection of the row labels and column labels

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have just seen your answer. I will try the code and come back.

Comment: The first solution works perfectly. The output of the second solution would be fine but I got an error: Error using accumarray
Second input VAL must be a vector with one element for each row in SUBS, or a scalar.

Comment: I fixed a bug in the following code, where the length should have been taken of unique values: secondresult = [A_hihi_expanded_unique accumarray(iA_hihi_expanded_unique, ones(1,length(A_hihi_expanded_unique)))]

Comment: Sorry, I still get the same error: Error using accumarray
Second input VAL must be a vector with one element for each row in SUBS, or a scalar.

Comment: It works for me though my sample data (A and B) may be different from yours.  There are two accumarray statements.  I need to know if the problem is at accumarray(ic,Bvals,{},@(x) {sort(x)})' or accumarray(iA_hihi_expanded_unique, ones(1,length(A_hihi_expanded_unique))).  Once that is narrowed down, I need to see an example of the input of (ic and Bvals) or (A_hihi_expanded_unique).  The literal problem is that the subs and val parameters do not have the same number of corresponding elements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34396/discussion-between-user2387053-and-will)